# (Substitute $ =, \subseteq, \supseteq $ to the place of $\bigcirc$) ,$\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B) \bigcirc \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus P(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\mathcal{P}$- the power set

I take the sets $A= {\{1,2,3 \} }$ and $B = \{ {1,2 \} }$

For $A =  \{ \emptyset, \{{ 1\},\{ 2\},\{ 3\},\{ 1,2\},\{ 1,3\},\{ 2,3\},\{ 1,2,3 \} }$

For $B =  \{ \emptyset, \{{ 1\},\{ 2\},\{ 1,2\}}$

For $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B) = \mathcal{P}{ \{ 3 \} } $ = $ \{ \emptyset, \{3 \} \}$

For $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B) = \{ \emptyset ,{\{ 1,3\},\{ 2,3\},\{ 1,2,3 \} }$

I think that this is a good counter example to show that $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B) \neq \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$

how can I continue it?

Comment: Guess: which one is seemingly "larger"? (Compare their cardinalities, especially for finite sets...)
Then, take an arbitrary element from a smaller set to see it actually also in a larger set.

Comment: None of the three relations holds in general and you would have a counterexample if only you had computed $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Should be $\subseteq$:

Let $x \in \mathcal{P}(A-B)$

$x \subseteq A-B$

$x \subseteq A$ & $x \nsubseteq B$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{P}(B)$

Comment: The implication $x \subseteq A \setminus B \implies x \subseteq A \mathbin{\text{&}} x \not \subseteq B$ fails for $x = \varnothing$ (which is also a counterexample to the inclusion $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$).